# AWS Free Tier services by usage - 1 GB of Amazon Elastic Block Storage snapshot storage | Unable to find where I am using storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In my free tier account I tried EC2 instances service, Load Balancer service and Elastic Beanstalk and RDS service.

I terminated all my EC2 instances, and RDS instances and Load Balancer, Beanstalk environment and snapshots of everything. Currently I did not have any snapshots and instances, balancer and volumes.

I am getting bill summary like:

```
1 GB of Amazon Elastic Block Storage snapshot storage   1 GB-mo 1 GB-mo 97.83%
```

[image: usage]

Please help to stop or reduce the usage.

Comment: Have you checked other regions? You may have some snapshots in other region(s) than you normally use.

Comment: **Side-note:** There is no such thing as a "free tier account". Rather, the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) provides a billing discount. If you only consume services within the Free Tier limits, you will not be charged for usage.

Comment: Take a look at that information again tomorrow to identify which amounts are changing. You can then then tell you which services are still being 'consumed'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start off by saying this is your actual usage (for the month) so if this is not going up day to day now then you are fine. Once billings rolls over the the next month you'll see this reset back down to zero.

Make sure you do not have any other resources laying around for example you forgot about a region you first used, these can then be deleted if you find them.

If this is still going up day to day AWS have a tool for you to analyse day to day spending with the ability to filter down to region and service, this is [AWS Cost Explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/). It is `$0.01` to run each query so make sure to configure what you're looking for before searching.

Answer (score 0):

You may have created EC2 instance that has created the snapshot for you. Look at a the Snapshot section  from the EC2 page, you see the snapshot the volume was created.